# why the query optimizer ignores the indexed view

Tags: sql-server

There is a query that returns some aggregation on the order table:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(InvoiceDate) AS InvoiceYear,
  COUNT(InvoiceID) AS InvoiceCount
FROM Sales.Invoices
GROUP BY YEAR(InvoiceDate);
```

..and I observe the following query plan:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the heavy hash match operator with an indexed view

```
CREATE or alter VIEW Sales.vSalesByYear
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    YEAR(InvoiceDate) AS InvoiceYear,
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS InvoiceCount
FROM Sales.Invoices
GROUP BY YEAR(InvoiceDate);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_vSalesByYear
    ON Sales.vSalesByYear (InvoiceYear);
GO
```

Why, when the query is repeated, the plan does not change, and the optimizer does not want to refer to the indexed view, because it will be easier for him?

If you directly access the view, then the plan that I want to see appears only after applying the hint (noexpand):

```
select 
  InvoiceYear
, InvoiceCount
 from Sales.vSalesByYear with (noexpand)
```

[image]

Comment: @Larnu It is a feature of indexed views that they may be considered by the optimizer even when they are not directly referenced from a query. It's only supported [in the Enterprise edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#RDBMSM).

Comment: Then the important question here is, are you using Enterprise, @Mikhail.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get to use Enterprise features often (apart from in developer edition) @GSerg , as I work in an environment with Standard only, so something I've never considered before. Plus, using Enterprise features in Dev environments would be foolhardy when deploying to a Standard environment. Thanks for the pointer if this is a Enterprise Feature.

Comment: @Mikhail, take a look at [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-performance/noexpand-hints).

Comment: @GSerg i use standart edition